# Node Js Http Get Event Listeners

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpresponse, event-listener

I wrote the following code to make an Http get request for a tutorial (learn you node). However I'm curious as to how this code works, I.e how am I able to register listeners to the response object after receiving it?

Isn't it possible for the response object to emit data or errors before I can register my listener for them?

```
const address = process.argv[2];
const http = require("http");

http
  .get(address, (response) => {
       
   response.setEncoding("utf8");
    response.on("data", console.log);
    response.on("error", console.error);
  })
  .on("error", console.error)
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback  "The callback is invoked with a single argument that is an instance of http.IncomingMessage."

Comment: Does the same question not stand for IncomingMessage? Could I not have missed an event it emitted by the time I'm able to register my listener?

Comment: Followup: from reading the docs on clientRequest, "If no 'response' handler is added, then the response will be entirely discarded. However, if a 'response' event handler is added, then the data from the response object must be consumed, either by calling response.read() whenever there is a 'readable' event, or by adding a 'data' handler, or by calling the .resume() method. Until the data is consumed, the 'end' event will not fire..." What if I don't register in time and it discards the response?